# How can I correctly run a java batch application (a .jar application) in background on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, java

I am not a system engineer (I am a software edeveloper).
I have to run a Java application (a runnable **.jar** file) on a Linux machine (Centos 7). I am connecting to a shell via SSH.
This application is in **jar** format and implement a batch application and containins itself its scheduler.

I have to run it in background on a remote server in order that after that I quit the shell it is still run.

I have performed this command in order to run my application in background:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

then I clicked on **CTRL+C** on my keyboard in order to obtain again the keyboard prompt on my shell.

and here the first trange behavior: I obtain again the shell prompt and the possibility to insert command but if the application log something it is appearing on the shell. Why? I expected that my application still run in background.

Anyway I now prompt this command in the my shell in order to check if my application is running:

```
xxx@xxx.yyy.it [~/zzz-import-data-batch]# ps aux | grep java
xxx 23307 15.3  1.6 4871172 418980 pts/0  Sl   10:23   0:22 java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
webadmin 23522  0.0  0.0 112812   980 pts/0    S+   10:25   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

And yes my application seems to correctly run (the first one).

Then I close the connection to my shell, I log into it again and I perform again the previous command but now I obtain this:

```
xxx@xxx.spaccount.it [~/zzz-import-data-batch]# ps aux | grep java
xxx 23919  0.0  0.0 112812   980 pts/0    S+   10:27   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

As you can see after that I disconnect from the shell, when I do a new login my batch application seems that it is not running (and infact my job application doesn't runned).

What is wrong? What am I missing? What could be a good way to run in background my java jar batch application?

Comment: Do you not want to set the application up as a service so it starts and stops together with the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disassociate the background job from the shell before the
shell is terminated.

When you entered `command &`, the system gave you a job-id that
looks like "[1] 25177", where `1` is the job-id.

You should use now the
[disown command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/).
For the above example, this would be:

```
disown 1
```

Or do all jobs (because you have only one):

```
disown
```

For more information, see for example
[Linux / Unix: disown Command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/).